# Implementing router link from typescript file angular 2 jquery kendo

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, kendo-grid

I have been using Jquery kendo in my angular 2 application. During implementation of kendo grid, i need to use routerlink from typescript file. I am currently using following code but its not working.

```
<button title= "Send Message" [routerLink] = "['messaging', ${senderId}]"> Send Message </button>
```

I have tried implementing click functions but using function in typescript file, it says **function is not defined**.
Help me!